# Could not download jaxb-core.jar (org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.2.11)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Today i update the android studio to 3.1 and having this issue in all my programs

> Could not download jaxb-core.jar
>   (org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.2.11): No cached version available for
>   offline mode

How can i fix this issue?[image]

Comment: Jcenter is currently having issues, most likely this is the probleme here as well. http://status.bintray.com/

Comment: Hi. Did you use `compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.1'`?